# What is the best practice for ensuring permissions are correct during the launch of an ASP.NET application

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, permissions

I have an ASP.NET application which requires write access on the App_Data subfolder. The MSI used to deploy the application tries to set the permissions correctly, but in spite of this, it seems the permissions are sometimes wrong.  Most of the application works fine without this permission.  I would prefer that the application fails to start if the permissions are wrong.

What is the best practice for ensuring that the necessary permissions are correct for the IIS user context?  Ideally I want to display some simple instructions for fixing whatever is wrong.  And I want the message to appear in as many incorrect configurations as possible.

The following describes what I've tried so far, until I realised there's a probably a better or standard way.

I tried putting this in `Application_Start()`

```
protected void Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Assert permissions on writeable folders are correct
    var permissionsChecker = new AppDataPermissionsChecker();
    permissionsChecker.AssertFolderIsWriteable(
        HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"));

    // remainder of Application_Start()...
}
```

where `AppDataPermissionsChecker` is defined as follows:

```
public class AppDataPermissionsChecker
{
    private bool CanWriteAccessToFolder(string folderPath)
    {
        try
        {
            // Attempt to get a list of security permissions from the folder. 
            // This will raise an exception if the path is read only or do not have access to view the permissions. 
            DirectorySecurity directorySecurity = Directory.GetAccessControl(folderPath);
            return true;
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void AssertFolderIsWriteable(string folderPath)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(folderPath))
            throw new Exception(String.Format("The {0} folder does not exist.", folderPath));
        if (!CanWriteAccessToFolder(folderPath))
            throw new Exception(String.Format("The ASPNET user does not have " 
                + "access to the {0} folder. Please ensure the ASPNET user has "
                + "read/write/delete access on the folder.  See 'The App_Data folder' "
                + "here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06t2w7da.aspx'",
         folderPath));
    }
}
```

I thought this would throw an ugly exception if the rights are incorrect (which is better than nothing), but in some situations I just get an HTTP Error 503.

Comment: what if permissions change while application is running? you still need a way to catch and display permission violation exception when performing actual App_Data write operation.

Comment: @Kuba, in my application it is unlikely the permissions would change after installation so I'm more interested in catching the problem at first launch.

Comment: Well...had a head injury over the weekend and not much sleep so I'm a bit fuzzy right now.  But there are security attributes you can decorate your assembly with defining the rights you need.  I just can't remember the attribute name right now.  I think it is [SecurityPermission()] and then look at the properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this [implementation of a diagnostics page](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/103625/Website-Diagnostics-Page-to-diagnose-your-ASP-NET) which does exactly what I was looking for (and more besides).